# Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback

Tags: node.js, redirect, localhost, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am following Traversy Media recent tutorial on nodejs from scratch and doing every thing as he doing but I don't know why I can't use this redirecting url **http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback** even though he(brad traversy the tutorial maker) can use.
[image: Picture showing that there is no error in using http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback url]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback
```

I used

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/callback
```

and also used 127.0.0.1 while making any request to server in my chrome browser. localhost is not allowed to be redirect uri. I found the allowed uris list here(Scroll down the half page to find allowed list) [Link of allowed redirect uris](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Google has changed their policy, but as of Jun 2021, callback url like http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback is working.